# MySQL complicated query. Dynamically Update rows from a table based on another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]

Above is a scheme I drew. There's an ideal case, when `content.user` are grouped. But usually they are not grouped.
What i meant in this scheme is:

1. At the first step, I select `users.monetos` WHERE `users.id = content.user`
2. At the second step, I decrement `users.monetos` with every `content.cpc` value (2.1 , 2.2)

When simulating this:
 select `content.user` (9)

select `users.monetos` Where `users.id=content.users` (15)

So we have 15 value for `users.monetos` for `users.id=9`, now we go back to content table
and:

1. decrement 15 value with 8 (`content.cpc`) (15-8=**7** > 0 -> go to step 2)
2. decrement 7 (result from previous step) with 10 (`content.cpc`) (7-10=-3 <0 -> update
   content set active='0' where content.id= (current id when a negative result obtained) )

And like this for every `content.user`

**More extended** - I want to select `contet.*` rows which have `content.active` = 1 **(n)**. Having this data, `SELECT` `users.monetos` WHERE `users.id`=`content.user` from previous query.
And now, by maximum **(n)** steps I decrement `users.monetos` value by **content.cpc** value 
and **on the moment when **users.monetos**=0 or less than 0, i want to update `content` and SET active='0'**

By words, I want like to share **users.monetos** amount to each **content** entry (**content.cpc** for each). And there's no more **users.monetos** make the current `content` 
entry inactive. And do this vor every **content.user**
What i'he done at this moment is shown below. I now it looks really bad, but I already don't know what to do.

```
$query = "select content.id, content.cpc, conent.user, content.active from content a
join users b on a.user=b.id
group by b.id where a.active='1'";

/** cycle each user **/
foreach($rows = $connector->fetchArray($query) as $row ) {
    $monetos = $row['monetos'];
    $query = "select id, cpc from content where user={$row['id']}";
    /** cycle each users content **/
    foreach($contents = $connector->fetchArray($query) as $content) {
        echo $monetos;
        $monetos -= $content['cpc'];
        if($monetos <= 0) {
            $disable[] = $content['id'];
        }
    }
    if( isset($disable) ) {
        $connector->query("update content set active='0' where id in(".implode(',',$disable).")");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really hard to help you, when you're not giving any data examples, or proper table structure. And when you're trying to implement some complex alghoritm, I think it would be better to draw a schema for easier understanding of your idea.

Comment: just give me a minute

Comment: @CrazySabbath there is. i will be very happy if you will take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
$query = "select * from users";
foreach($rows = $connector->fetchArray($query) as $row ) {
    $a='';
$query = "select * from content where user='{$row[id]}' and active='1' ";
foreach($contents = $connector->fetchArray($query) as $content ) {
    $a++;
    $a_min=$a-1;
    $test[$a]=$row[monetos]-$content[cpc];      
    if($a==2){
        if($test[$a_min] > 0){
            $test2=$test[$a_min]-$content[cpc];
            if($test2 < 0){
                $connector->query("update content set active='0' where id='$content[id]'");
            }
        }
    }
}   
}
```